# What are the parameters before the $x^n$ factors called in a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

> Consider
>   $$ax^n + bx^{n-1} + cx^{n-2} + \cdots + mx^2 + nx + q$$
>   What are the numbers $a, b, c,\ldots,m,n,q$ called?

Imagine the polynomial on a test, and instead of $a, b, c,\ldots,m,n,q$ there are blank spaces. You are to fill in numbers in those spaces. The test directs you to fill in the blanks with ______ .

What are those numbers called?

Comment: The coefficients. If we have $f\in R[x]$, then they are elements of $R$.

Comment: $a$ and $q$ might also have special names beyond just "coefficients" as well.  $a$ might be called the *leading coefficient* and $q$ might be called the *constant*.